# overwriting data saved with isolated storage settings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

as part of my app I need to save info to isolated storage settings, I have done this. I now need to overwrite the data that is already saved. is this possible? and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Save it again with new data. Old data will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to overwrite:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["myKey"] = "something";
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["myKey"] = "something different";
```

The same way you set your value originally, just do that again with the same key. The original value will be overwritten.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, do I need to use INotifyPropertyChange? or should it do it with out it?

Comment: You won't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this. If you're curious, though, you can refer to this example for when/how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure you can remove the previous data with same key and then write it again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IsolatedStorage I would suggest creating a class to encapsulate your information that is then saved to IsoStorage. Here is a [great blog](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/01/09/Strongly-type-your-settings-saved-in-IsolatedStorageSettings.aspx) on doing that. This approach allows you to do the following

```
mySettings.MyProperty = newValue;
mySettings.Save();
```